# RecyclerView Adapter inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I set a recycler adapter in fragment inside firebase OnCompleteListener. So, the problem is when I am navigating between fragments quickly (by Navigation View), I have an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity". Android studio gives me the link to that line of my code:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterRV(requireActivity(), listLeft, listRight));
```

As I understand the main issue is

```
requireActivity()
```

I found some solutions as:

```
view.getContext()

requireContext()
```

What is the right one for my case? Or may be there is some better way to fix this?

Comment: Post the complete class where you're calling `recyclerView.setAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario app throws an exception because of once data arrives and we intent to pass them to the recyclerview, your fragment will be disattached and it causes an exception

and in my opinion the solution would be something like this...

### **Better Way :**

You should add a method to your adapter for pass data:

in ***OnViewCreated*** :

```
adapter = new AdapterRV(requireActivity())
```

when data ***received***

```
adapter.submitList(listLeft, listRight)
```

### **Another Way :**

if you have to set adapter after arrive the data,
you need to call adapter after checking if the context is not null

```
if ( getContext() != null ) 
{
recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterRV(requireActivity(), listLeft, listRight));
}
```